# find command to list symbolic link files not working in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

[bash script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVEaP.png)

Im trying to make a script that lists all symbolic link files in a directory but the command im using doesnt seem to work in the script but works when i use it in the terminal.

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8H6i.png)

Comment: It's hard to entirely tell from here, but it could be an issue of quotes and variables.  Try ${directory}, and get rid of quotes around the command.

Also, best to copy the text / commands into the question.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=linux+find+broken+links

Answer (score 1):

You can try these options and see what fits to your need best.

**Pseudo code:**

```
   #!/usr/bin/bash
    find . -type l -ls
    #To only process the current directory:
    #find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls
```

**More find commands to list symbolic link in dir:**

```
find -L /dir/to/start -xtype l -samefile ~/Pictures 2>/dev/null.
find / -lname /path/to/original/dir
```

- L - Follow symbolic links.
- xtype l - File is symbolic link
- samefile name - File refers to the same inode as name. When -L is in effect, this can include symbolic links.